# Setting default URL parameters on view page

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking, url

Is there a way on an overridden page to specify certain URL parameters?  Specifically, I'm looking to set the "rowsperlist" for a related list.

This is how I'd like the overridden URL to look for a related list w/ ID "CorrList" on a page w/ ID "MyContact":

```
/apex/MyContact_CustomView?id=AAA000000000000111&sfdc.override=1&MyContact%3ACorrList%3Arowsperlist=80
```

FYI - The related list is identified as MyContact:CorrList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I should have used the "pageSize" parameter for the related list:

```
<apex:relatedList id="CorrList" list="Correspondence_To_Contacts__r" title="Correspondence" pageSize="500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible, because overriding the standard 'view' link for an sObject only allows you to specify a Visualforce page (or an S-Control), and to do this you would need to be able to specify a URL.

Workarounds for this require a controller extension. I think it's a safe assumption that you are using a controller extension, since you wouldn't be able to use your URL parameters otherwise.

Possible workarounds:

- Hard-code the default(s) for your `rowsperlist` variable in the constructor of the controller extension instead of pulling it from `pagereference.getParameters()`
- Set up a custom setting to hold your default value (or values), and pull the custom setting in the constructor of the controller extension

Comment: Sorry - I never posted the answer - I didn't see the parameter for the related list before, and that did what I was looking to do.  I didn't have a custom controller, since the object and its relationships are so complicated that pulling everything needed by the page was a mess (apparently "agile" can mean "we change our requirements every 20 minutes")